# Where are these unexpected characters appearing from in write.table?

Tags: r

I have three strings which I want to bind as rows and pass to the clipboard via write.table(). When I do so I find a lot of junk characters are added and I can't find out where they come from. I'm presuming this is an issue with my setup, but here's the data and code to see if this is reproducible.

```r
strings <- c("\\textit{LTG health} & -.91 (-.91, -.90) & -.90 (-.90, -.90) & -.91 (-.91, -.90) & -.85 (-.86, -.84) & -.91 (-.92, -.91) & -.90 (-.91, -.90) & -.91 (-.91, -.90) & -.85 (-.86, -.84) \\\\", 
"\\textit{LLTI} & -.85 (-.85, -.84) & -.84 (-.85, -.83) & -.85 (-.86, -.84) & -.79 (-.80, -.78) & -.84 (-.85, -.83) & -.83 (-.84, -.83) & -.83 (-.84, -.82) & -.77 (-.78, -.76) \\\\", 
"\\textit{Mortality (2011)} & -.41 (-.43, -.39) & -.39 (-.42, -.37) & -.41 (-.43, -.39) & -.45 (-.47, -.43) & -.56 (-.58, -.54) & -.54 (-.56, -.52) & -.56 (-.58, -.54) & -.59 (-.61, -.57) \\\\"
)

write.table(strings, "clipboard", col.names = F, row.names = F, quote = F)
```

When I paste into a plain text editor I get the following full of unexpected characters and the third line appears to be lost entirely. I can't post the actual data because SO is detecting the junk characters as spam, so here's a screenshot:
[image: Screenshot of spammy characters.]

**EDITS**

If I use paste() to concatenate into a single row, the junk characters don't appear.

Setting the fileEncoding in write.table to UTF-8 does not fix the problem.

Comment: it could be an issue with your encoding.  I couldn't reproduce the issue with the example showed

Comment: Thanks akrun. Are there some R/RStudio/OS options that I might be set incorrectly somewhere? I don't use any other languages in my OS so it shouldn't be anything to do with that.

Comment: You may specify the `fileEncoding` in `write.table`

Comment: No luck, but thanks for the suggestion.